# Inconsistent Gradle Dependency Resolution

Tags: gradle

I'm receiving error *"Did not resolve 'ch.randelshofer:fastdoubleparser:0.8.0' which is part of the dependency lock state"* during Gradle project build in Jenkins server. I am using Gradle dependency locking and write the lockfile in my local machine. I've tried to match the environment of my local machine to the Jenkins server i.e., matching the Java and Gradle version. However there are some specification that I can't match e.g., OS (Windows/Ubuntu WSL to RedHat).

The weird thing is, my local machine and Jenkins resolve some of the dependencies differently. In this case 3 library from about 200 dependencies, the other just resolved consistently. These dependencies: `ch.randelshofer:fastdoubleparser`, `org.junit:junit-bom` and `org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api` weren't resolved by Jenkins. I've tried in different local machine, all of them resolve just like mine.

I've tried run it on different Java (17 and 21) and Gradle (8.1.1, 8.2 and 8.2.1) version, different OS (Windows and Ubuntu WSL), different laptop, they all are consistent. I've also tried clearing cache. Describing the Jenkins server, it's using Java 17, Gradle 8.1.1 and OS RedHat.

So, why is the Jenkins resolve it differently?

I've tried to list the dependency tree as the result can be seen below. To help you focus on the branch that is different, I've put marks `FOCUS_ON_ME!!!` right on their side.

- Dependecy tree from my local machine

  ```
  ...
  compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
  +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.0
  |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.1.0 (*)
  |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:3.1.0
  |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.1.0 (*)
  |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.9
  |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.0.9 (*)
  |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.9 (*)
  |    |    |    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:1.10.7 -> 1.11.0
  |    |    |         \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:1.11.0
  |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0
  |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0
  |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0
  |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.15.0 (c)
  |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |    |    +--- ch.randelshofer:fastdoubleparser:0.8.0
  |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0 (*)
  |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.0 (*)
  |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.15.0

  testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
  +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.0
  |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3
  |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |    |    \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
  |    |    |    \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
  |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |    |    \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
  |    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |         +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |         |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
  |    |         |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.3 (*)
  |    |         |    \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
  |    |         +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.2
  |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:5.3.1
  ...
  ```
- Dependency tree from Jenkins server

  ```
  ...
  compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
  +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.0
  |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.1.0 (*)
  |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:3.1.0
  |    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.1.0 (*)
  |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.9
  |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.0.9 (*)
  |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.9 (*)
  |    |    |    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:1.10.7 -> 1.11.0
  |    |    |         \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:1.11.0
  |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0
  |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0
  |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.15.0

  testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
  +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.0
  |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3
  |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.3
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3 (c)
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 (c)
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3 (c)
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.3 (c)
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.3 (c)
  |    |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.9.3 (c)
  |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
  |    |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |         \--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |         +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.9.3 FOCUS_ON_ME!!!
  |    |         |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.3 (*)
  |    |         |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
  |    |         |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.3 (*)
  |    |         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3 (*)
  |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:5.3.1
  ...
  ```